How to set a range in a list to group items in that range?
`I tried to make a template in Zotero Integration to import notes from Zotero to Obsidian.
This is the code I have:
{%- set ParrafoIndex = 1 -%}
{%- set prevtAnnot = null -%}  {# Inicializamos la variable prevtAnnot #}
{%- for annotation in annotations -%}
  {%- if annotation.type == "note" and annotation.colorCategory == "Purple" -%} 
     {{annotation.type}} - {{annotation.colorCategory}} - Encabezado de Parrafo {{ ParrafoIndex }}
    {%- set ParrafoIndex = ParrafoIndex + 1 %}
  {%- else -%}
    > {{annotation.type}} - {{annotation.colorCategory}}
  {%- endif -%}
  {{ "" }}
  {{ "" }}
{%- endfor -%}

This code print the annotations in a list like:
Purple: Paragraph 1

Yellow: Annotation 1

Blue: Annotation 2

Yellow: Annotation 3

Red: Annotation 4

Green: Annotation 5

Green: Annotation 6


Purple: Paragraph 2
I want to organize the annotations (Yellow, Green, Blue, Red) between two annotations with the "Purple" color category. The list should look like:
Purple: Paragraph 1

Yellow: Annotation 1

Yellow: Annotation 3

Green: Annotation 5

Green: Annotation 6

Blue: Annotation 2

Red: Annotation 4


Purple: Paragraph 2
anyone know how to order the list in that form?`

Do you want sort annotations by their colors with the next priorities Yellow < Green < Blue < Red? Is it correct?
